# Does use of mutexes or atomics require special handling at thread startup?

Tags: visual-c++, stdthread

I'm attempting to run multiple threads in which each thread operates on an item referenced by a shared index into a shared vector. Each thread is started with a reference to the common vector and index, and some form of synchronization is used to control updating of the index so that each thread works on a unique index and all indices in the vector eventually get covered. Things seem to work for all indices except the first few. If there are 4 threads started, the first 3 indices consistently are skipped. Either I am doing something wrong with the synchronization or there is something special about thread startup which makes the first attempts at synchronization fail.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, c++ toolset v141 and SDK version 10.0.17134.0. 
Also I'm using the standard lib, not boost (or anything else).

Here is the code within main...

```
vector<string> dirs;
string ipath;
//dirs and ipath get filled in with some valid path strings...
const int64_t maxthreads = 4;
vector<thread> mythreads;
atomic<int64_t> common_index{-1};
for(int64_t i = 0l i < maxthreads; ++i)
{ 
 mythreads.push_back(thread(runthreads,ref(dirs),cref(ipath),ref(common_index)));
}
for(int64_t i = 0; i < maxthreads; ++i)
{
 mythreads[i].join();
}
```

and here is the code within runthreads

```
void runthreads(vector<string>& dirs, const string& ipath, atomic<int64_t>& cindex)
{
   try
   {
      const int64_t max_index = dirs.size();
      while(true)
      {
        int64_t use_index;
        int64_t tindex = cindex.load();
        do
        {
           use_index = tindex + 1;
        } while (!cindex.compare_exchange_weak(tindex, use_index));

        if(use_index < max_index)
        {
          string use_path = ipath + dirs[use_index];
          //do work on use_path
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }
      }
   }
   catch (...)
   {
   }
}
```

The idea was for each thread to get the current index value, set a desired new value (increment by one), attempt to update the common index in an atomic manner, only succeeding if the current value matches the expected value. If successful, the saved use_index value must be the current index to operate on and the code proceeds. I expect every index to be covered, but the first 3 (when there are 4 threads started) get skipped. I don't understand what is wrong with the approach.

I tried using a global atomic for the index rather than passing in a ref, and I also tried just using a non-atomic index and enclosing the update of the index in a block with a mutex and lock_guard. I also tried adding some sort of atomic_thread_fence, though it seems to me I shouldn't need to, as the atomic operations I'm using by default have memory_order_seq_cst. Ultimately, I always get the same behavior...missing the first three indices.

If I add a pause between starting up new threads, such as adding

```
thread::sleep_for(50ms);
```

after the thread creation line, those initial indices get processed. I imagine the most likely issue is that I'm misunderstanding something in my implementation, but I don't know what it is. Otherwise, I wonder if special handling at thread startup is required (something other than just inserting delays with "sleep_for") in order for those synchronization approaches to work correctly.

Comment: You have an infinite `while(true)` loop. I don't see any means of existing it. The code as written would just have all threads spin forever. I don't see how it can process any indexes, whether first three or otherwise.

Comment: Also, you are reinventing [`fetch_add`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add)

Comment: @Igor, thanks for looking. I edited my original code snippet to show the break from the while loop. You're right in that this is essentially fetch_add and I had tried this as well as the other approaches I mentioned, but all behaved the same way as described....all indices except the first ones processed, and adding a sleep at thread startup results in the first ones being processed as well.

Comment: [Works for me](https://rextester.com/UEXM72138)

Comment: Thanks for the time in checking. The same code built here locally most definitely doesn't work for me and it should, as it did for you. Thank you though.

Comment: you need to show the complete code.  How are you initializing `dirs`?  What is the "work" you are doing with`use_path`?

Comment: Also how can you tell it isn't processing the first few indices?